# Put selected text in variable to add to query

Tags: vim

Hello I am trying put the selected text into a variable then add it to a string i want to execute. 
Here is my list i want to use

```
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE name\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_contact_us\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_customer\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_order\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_to_cart\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_to_wish_list\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE add_transaction\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE clear_cart\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE get_order_contents\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE get_shopping_cart_contents\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE get_wish_list_contents\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE receipt_retrieve\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE remove_from_cart\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE remove_from_wish_list\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE select_categories\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE select_products\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE select_sale_items\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE update_cart\G
 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE update_wish_list\G
```

here is the function that creates these lines

```
function Myproc()
r !mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SELECT name FROM mysql.proc;'
let q = 'mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e'
echom q
normal! gg /name
normal! ndd
%normal! I SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE 
normal! ggdd0 
%normal A\G
normal! gg0
//here where im having porblems.. i think
normal! <shift>.Vy\<C-r>".q 

endfunction
```

What i want is to build a query string and output it so i can see and edit stored procedures
the string should look like

```
!mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE update_wish_list\G
```

new to vim an i on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is I think a better way to write this script:

```
" get proc names from mysql and split them into an list
let output = system("mysql -uroot -ppass sas -e 'SELECT name FROM mysql.proc'")
let proc_list = split(output, '\n')

"set cursor to first line
call cursor('1', '1')

" output as you like
for proc in proc_list
    put ='SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE ' . proc .'\G'
endfor
```

and of cause you can wrap it as a function too.